# WAI-ARIA Container Roles That List Children

Tags: wai-aria

Using the ChromeVox extension as a screen reader, I noticed that menus with `role="menu"` that are `ul` tags, with `role="menuitem"` children that are or are inside of `li` descendants, will trigger the description: **"menu with N items"**

I also noticed that when using a different tag, such as:

```
<div role="menu">
    <div role="menuitem">1</div>
    <div role="menuitem">2</div>
</div>
```

It will not trigger the **"menu with 2 items"** audio output. Instead it will only say **"menu"**.

In a similar fashion, I am looking for another container role that allows me to lists elements that might not be a menu or even links (example: a list of articles), but having it say **"with N items"**.

Why does this work only with `ul` tags in the case of `role="menu"`? What other tags does it work in? Where is this documented in the official docs? What tag and role combination can I use for lists that are not menus, but also have the *"with n items"* text read out loud?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this occurs with `li` elements is that [they expose a `setsize`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aam-1.0/#el-li) property value in accessibility APIs. This is inherited when the native HTML `listitem` role is overridden by the ARIA `menuitem` role. `div` elements don't expose this property. In order to expose the setsize property on `<div role="menuitem">` you will need to use the '[aria-setsize](https://www.w3.org/TR/core-aam-1.1/#ariaSetsize)' attribute.